# Apache error log showing very strange problems

Tags: apache, error-log

I was wondering if anyone could point out what is causing the problem in the screenshot attached. It has happened a couple of times with different images. I can't see what is causing it.

The machine is my development machine.

I was hoping to post this on serverfault but I can't add the image I need.[image: Apache Error Log]

Comment: What is the code on `http://10.0.0.10:8080/layout/` doing?

Comment: Nothing special, its just where I am coding the front end to a site

Comment: At first glance, I'm guessing you have some javascript dynamically loading an img src, and it's in a loop?  Would be easier if we could see some code...

Comment: No javascrpit loading images, just css.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info yet, so just some debugging steps.

1. Try uploading it to a different machine and see if you get these same messages.
2. Check you don't have any Javascript doing anything with image urls - to me it looks like some loop somewhere might be going 'wacko', but could be client or server side.
3. Use tail -F on it in the terminal and refresh the page to see if the appearance of those entries coincides with the loading of the page.

Edit: maybe also have Firebug/etc open when you refresh the page with their Network panels open to see if you really are sending those requests. Really just want to find if it's a client or server issue to begin with.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I will try and recreate the error but having difficulty doing so. Its happened about 4/5 times, but not for a while now. There is no javascript loading any images, css does though.